# How can I continue execution of the current block after an INSERT failure?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Consider the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrderingTest](
    [ColKey] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Col0] [int] NULL,
    [Col1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Col2] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

... and the following batch:

```
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO OrderingTest(Col0,Col1,Col2)
  VALUES (1,NULL,3);

  SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END;
```

The `Test` table does not allow `NULL` values in Col1, so the insert will fail. I was hoping to test for failure using the value of `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` at this point. However, instead of seeing the `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` produce a single row with a `NULL` column as output, execution of the batch terminates after the failed insert and the `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` line is never executed.

**UPDATE:**

I was incorrect the result of `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` was displayed in the Results pane. I was confused, because SSMS switched the Messages pane into focus instead of the Results pane (since an error occurred).

However the latest value of the identity column, `ColKey`, is displayed instead of `NULL` after a failed `INSERT`. I thought `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is supposed to return NULL if an `INSERT` fails.

Comment: Any reason not to use the TRY CATCH error handling in SQL 2008?

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having to put one or more inserts into a TRY block? That is for the current scope, I want inserts not to fail throw an exception if they fail, but SCOPE_IDENTITY to return NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried these commands:

```
BEGIN   
    DECLARE @theKey INT
    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO OrderingTest(Col0,Col1,Col2)   
        VALUES (1,NULL,3);    
        SELECT @theKey = SCOPE_IDENTITY();      
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
         SET @theKey = - 1
    END CATCH
    select @theKey
END;
```

And the following

```
BEGIN   
    DECLARE @theKey INT
    SET @theKey = 1
        INSERT INTO OrderingTest(Col0,Col1,Col2)   
        VALUES (1,NULL,3);    
        SELECT @theKey = SCOPE_IDENTITY();      
    select @theKey

END;
```

In both cases, the `SELECT @theKey` was executed, although in the second example, an error message was displayed to the print window.   Note that in your example, you are trying to insert into the TEST table, rather than OrderingTest table.   This will produce an error and not run the SELECT.   Are you sure your example is right?

Note that in this example, SCOPE_IDENTITY returns the identity from the last successful INSERT, not NULL

```
BEGIN   
INSERT INTO OrderingTest(Col0,Col1,Col2)   VALUES (1,2,3);    

INSERT INTO OrderingTest(Col0,Col1,Col2)   VALUES (1,NULL,3);    
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY(); 
END;
```

Comment: I've updated the table name in my question, `OrderingTest` is the correct table name.

Comment: So do you get the same behavior I am seeing in the second example (the SELECT command is getting executed and the script continues)

Comment: Yes, but why IS SCOPE_IDENTITY() not returning NULL?

Comment: When I run the example code, SCOPE_IDENTITY() is returning NULL.   Note that is another INSERT occurs within the block, Scope_identity will return that successful INSERT Identity key instead...