# Re-run a stored procedure until it finnishes without errors in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedures that does a lot of inserts using openquery. Because of reasons beyond my influence the connection often breaks between linked servers and I need to run the procedure couple of times. What is the best (I am guessing try and catch block) way to automatically re-run the procedure until it finishes without errors.

Comment: you can use a sql server agent job that retries upon failure a specified number of times: http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2012/automatically-retry-a-sql-server-job-after-a-failed-step/

Comment: No need to re-run.use this [link][1] to continue insert from last point.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273885/how-can-i-continue-execution-of-the-current-block-after-an-insert-failure